# Datastudio: Is it possible to use tables as data sources for ie. pie chart?

Tags: looker-studio

I have few tables filtered differently to show different totals about landing pages. I would like to use that totals to draw pie chart based solely on totals. Is that possible in Google Datastudio, or am I using it wrong?

Comment: Do you mean you have several separate metric totals that you want to use? If so, no a pie chart can only represent 1 metric divided by dimension values. If that's not what you mean, can you provide an example of your data structure?

Comment: No, it's the same metric in all tables - Page views per user, it's just filtered out differently, resulting in different totals.

Comment: so are they all in the same data source or different ones?

Comment: Same data source

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clarification. I think it might be possible using a calculated metric to create a new dimension that reflects your filter conditions. For example:

```
CASE WHEN yourDimension = "Yourfiltercondition1" then "TotalFilter1"
ELSE WHEN yourDimension = "Yourfiltercondition2" then "TotalFilter2"
ELSE "TotalFilter3"
END
```

Obviously you may need to use different functions to reflect your filters (IN, REGEXP_MATCH(), etc) and if you have any table filters which contain the same values then you may struggle to get something that is exactly the same as your tables.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll give it a try and report back if it works.